# Number of points where $f'(x) = 0$ for $f( x ) = 2^x − x^2$.

Tags: functions

I am approaching this question via graphs but not able to conclude whether or not graphs intersect or at how many points they do. Please explain this question without seeing the actual graph.

Comment: Why not just say "where $f'(x)=0?$" Functions doesn't intersect the $x$ axis, their graphs do.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews From a set-theoretic point of view a function and its graph are the same object.

Comment: Which is why the set-theoretic point of view is often unhelpful.

Comment: First, you have to compute $f'$, Amarnath. Why not show us that first?

Comment: Do you know any calculus?  Do you know what $f'(x)$ is?  Note that $g(x) - h(x) = 0 \iff g(x) = h(x)$ and also note that $h(x)= 2x$ is a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g=f'$. Then the question reduces to find the number of zero of $g$. Let's investigate the behaviour of $g$.\begin{align*}g(x)&=2^x(\ln2)-2x\\
g'(x)&=2^x(\ln2)^2-2\\
g''(x)&=2^x(\ln2)^3>0\quad\forall~x\in\mathbb{R}\end{align*}
So $g$ is a strictly convex function, which means $g$ at most one local minimum and no other turning points. Solving $g'(x)=0$, we have $2^x=\dfrac{2}{(\ln2)^2}$ and $x=1-2\dfrac{\ln(\ln2)}{\ln2}:=x_0$. Note $g(x_0)<0$ because $$2^{x_0}(\ln2)-2x_0=\dfrac{2}{\ln2}-2+4\dfrac{\ln(\ln2)}{\ln2}<0$$
While one can see as $x\to-\infty$, $2^x$ vanishes and $2x\to\infty$ so $g\to+\infty$, and as $x\to+\infty$, $2^x>>2x$, so $g\to+\infty$. This gives the rise of using intermediate value theorem on some closed intervals between $(-\infty,x_0)$ and $(x_0,+\infty)$ (For example $[-1,x_0]$ and $[x_0,1000]$, check $g(-1),g(1000)>0$.) By the monotonicity of $g$, there cannot be anymore zero.

So in sum, there are two zeroes.

Answer (score -1):

$$\forall x\in  \mathbb R, 2^x:=\exp(x\log2)$$where $\log x$ is, of course, the
'Napierian' logarithm of $x$, to base $\mathrm e$.

So, $$\color{red}{f'(x)}=\log 2\exp(x\log 2)-2x$$ $$\color{blue}{f''(x)}=(\log2)^2\exp(x\log 2)-2$$

You then have to make a **table of variations**(see [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variations_d%27une_fonction) for example)  to prove that there are two values $a$ and $b$ of $x$ for which $f'(x)=0$, using $c=1-2\frac{\log(\log 2)}{\log 2}\approx2.06$ and your course results that it is a unique opportunity to review or learn([exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function), [monotonic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function),  [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) ,...)

Hint : use $\color{green}{f(-1)=-\frac12,f(0)=1,f(2)=f(4)=0}$ and [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) too.

---

I think it doesn't make sense not to rely on the real graph since these are essentially graphical results

[image]
https://www.geogebra.org/classic/uwsryu6g